# In iphone how to check that a call is success or not in xcode?

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

i have to check that whether a  call made on a number by code is success or not ,if not then i have to make another call on another number.....

```
-(IBAction)callPhone:(id)sender {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:2135554321"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Apple does not provide you any information about calls at all. You won't know whether the phone actually *tried* making the call (other than `openURL:` might return NO if the URL was invalid or some other error occurred).

This is by design and intended to protect the users' privacy.

Answer (score 3):

You can refer CoreTelephony Framework ([CTCall Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009590)).This class has a property `callState` that returns states of cellular calls i.e. dialing, incoming, connected, or disconnected.